# AngularJS ng-model selecting wrong `<option>`

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

On my edit form i want the select box select with the value inserted in the database. i am using ng-model to select the value 
problem is that it always select the first option

from angular js

```
 $scope.form.language_id=2
```

my html select box

```
<div class="form-group row" >
    <label class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label col-form-label">{{phrase.Language}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select  class="form-control" id="language_id" ng-model="form.language_id" name="language_id" required >
            <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in langs" value="{{value.id}}">{{value.languageTitle}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

json image 
[image]

point to notice is that it always selecting the first option dont know why

Comment: can you share your json?

Comment: Generally recommended to use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` to create the <option> elements

Comment: check the update question

Comment: Try with string `$scope.form.language_id="2"`.

Comment: not working with $scope.form.language_id="2"

Comment: bhaumik shah check the updated json image

Comment: Have you parsed Your Data ?

Comment: use ng-options.

Comment: use $scope.form.$valid

Comment: The `value` attribute returns strings and the `object.id` is a number. Use `ng-value` without curly bracket `{{ }}` interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.form={"language_id":2};
$scope.langs=[
{"id":1,"languageTitle":"test1"},
{"id":2,"languageTitle":"test2"},
{"id":3,"languageTitle":"test3"},
]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="form-group row" >
<label class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label col-form-label">{{phrase.Language}}</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select  class="form-control" id="language_id" ng-model="form.language_id"
         name="language_id" required
         ng-options="lan.id as lan.languageTitle for lan in langs">
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using NgRepeat you should use the [NgOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive which is build for the select tag.

Here's a working example

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("optionCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.form.language_id = 2;
  $scope.langs = [
  { id: 1,languageTitle: 'Eng' },
  { id: 2,languageTitle: 'Swe' },
  { id: 3,languageTitle: 'Fra' }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="optionCtrl" class="form-group row" >
 <label class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label col-form-label">{{phrase.Language}}</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <select class="form-control" 
    id="language_id" 
    ng-model="form.language_id" 
    name="language_id" 
    ng-options="item.id as item.languageTitle for item in langs"
    required >
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marcus Höglund and Sagar Raviprolu you guyzzz solve by problem thankss alottttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute returns strings and the `value.id` is a number. Use `ng-value` without curly bracket `{{ }}` interpolation.

```
    <select  ng-model="form.language_id" name="language_id" required >
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in langs" ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶.̶i̶d̶}̶}̶
                ng-value="value.id">
           {{value.languageTitle}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

From the Docs:

> In general, the match between the model and an option is evaluated by strictly comparing the model value against the value of the available options.
>
> If you are setting the option value with the option's `value` attribute, or textContent, the value will always be a `string` which means that the model value must also be a string. Otherwise the `select` directive cannot match them correctly.
>
> To bind the model to a non-string value, you can use one of the following strategies:
>
> - the `ngOptions` directive ([`select`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value))
> - the `ngValue` directive, which allows arbitrary expressions to be option values ([Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngvalue-to-bind-the-model-to-an-array-of-objects))
> - model $parsers / $formatters to convert the string value ([Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#binding-select-to-a-non-string-value-via-ngmodel-parsing-formatting))

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.form={"language_id":2};
$scope.langs=[
{"id":1,"languageTitle":"test1"},
{"id":2,"languageTitle":"test2"},
{"id":3,"languageTitle":"test3"},
]
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select ng-model="form.language_id" name="language_id" required >
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in langs" ng-value="value.id">
           {{value.languageTitle}}
        </option>
    </select>

</body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [AngularJS ng-value Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)